# "People leave their premises permanently when they are old."

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Dictionaries define *retire* as "to leave your job or stop working because of old age."

Can I rephrase it like below by saying "leaving a workplace forever"?

> People leave **their premises permanently** when they are old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three problems with using *leave their premises*.

1. *Premises* are properties of the business, so only businessowners leave ***their*** premises when they retire.
2. *Premises* includes all the contiguous owned locations, interior and exterior, most of which will be beyond the workplace of a particular individual.
3. Today more than ever before it is quite possible to be employed by a firm without ever setting foot on its *premises*.

When you retire what you are leaving is not a place but a role and an activity.